# How to enable "Synchronize across time zones" option with Schtasks.exe

Tags: scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments, time-zone

I need to create a schedule task in 1000+ machines which should be running at the same time hence decided to use the option of "***Synchronize across time zones***". For deploying in these machines, I am creating a batch file which will call *[Schtasks.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx)* with its command line switches. But did not get the option for enabling "Synchronize across time zones" option.

Please guide

Comment: This answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49542203/10592356 -- talks about passing an XML file to SchTasks.exe and using the `<StartBoundary/>` element to get that option enabled. Give that a try.